# pyspark- how to add a column to spark dataframe from a list

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm looking for a way to add a new column in a Spark DF from a list. In pandas approach it is very easy to deal with it but in spark it seems to be relatively difficult. Please find an examp

```
#pandas approach
list_example = [1,3,5,7,8]
df['new_column'] = list_example

#spark ?
```

Could you please help to resolve this tackle (the easiest possible solution)?

Comment: I remember this is not possible, but the reason escapes me.

Comment: A new DF or if 5 rows you want 1..8 each assigned to a value out of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

list_example = [1,3,5,7,8]
new_df = df.withColumn("new_column",  F.array( [F.lit(x) for x in list_example] ))
new_df.show()
```

Comment: Unclear if this is what is meant. But may be.

Comment: I need simliar thing but it is list of string any idea how to handle this